# Buidling BST in racket from a list

Tags: scheme, racket

I introduce today is to make a BST tree using a list. This is a list with sorted version, and strictly increasing, with no duplicates. like (list 100 200 300 400)..

Ialready write alot of code. It is here. but nothing is works..Can some one change it to fix?

Thank you

```
(define (bst-tree lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst) empty]
    [else
     (local [(define (pivot lst)
               (cond
                 [(= 1 (length lst)) (first lst)]
                 [(= 2 (length lst)) (first lst)]
                 [else (pivot (rest (foldl cons empty (rest (foldl cons empty lst)))))]))
             
             (define less (filter (lambda (x) (< x (pivot lst))) lst))
             (define greater (filter (lambda (x) (> x (pivot lst))) lst))]
       
       (append (make-node pivot (bst-tree less) (bst-tree greater))))]))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the fix: `(append (make-node`**`(pivot lst)`**`(bst-tree less) (bst-tree greater)))`

`pivot` refers to the function, and therefore evaluates to a procedure applying it on the list gets the numeric value.